# SQL query to find recent data and compare rows

Tags: sql

With the following information, I need to create a SQL query to select the appropriate data and output the data based on the first 2 entries when sorted by date of visit (which includes time).

> INPUT:
> Table with 3 columns: license place of the vehicle, visited city, date of visit

> ALGORITHM:
> If 2 most recent visits (first 2 entries) of the vehicle are in the same city, then `print` into output.
>
> Else If 2 most recent visits (first 2 entries) are in different city then no output.

> OUTPUT:
> license plate of the vehicle, last visited city

Example:

```
License_plate    City       Date
ABC123           Berlin     1-JAN-2020
ABC123           Berlin     10-FEB-2020
ABC123           Munich     15-MAR-2020
ABC123           Munich     18-MAR-2020
EFG456           Berlin     5-JAN-2020
EFG456           Munich     10-MAR-2020
EFG456           Berlin     1-JUN-2020
```

In the example the only online line in the output will be:

```
ABC123     Munich
```

`EFG456` is not included as last two recent visit were in different cities

Comment: Pl mention the database.

Answer (score 0):

You can use window functions (if your database supports them) to filter on the last two visits per licence plate, and then aggregation to get groups that relate to one city only:

```
select license_plate, min(city) city
from (
    select t.*, row_number() over(partition by license_plate order by date desc) rn
    from mytable t
) t
where rn <= 2
group by license_plate
having min(city) = max(city)
```